# Approximation to the $n$-th derivative using reproducing kernels.

Tags: convolution, dirac-delta, hermite-polynomials, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces, deconvolution

For integrable functions defined on the real line, the normalized gaussian function approximates the convolution identity, Dirac Delta, in the sense that if
$$g(t):=N_0e^{-x²}$$
(denoting the normalizing constant by $N_0$)
and 
$$g_{a0}(x):=aN_0e^{-(ax)²}$$
then, for all $f$ integrable,
$$\lim_{a\to\infty} f*g_{a0}=f$$
almost everywhere.

My **first question** is: Is this true?

My **second question** is: does the $n$-th derivative of the Gaussian function approximates the derivade operator by convolution? I mean writing
$$g_{an}:=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} g_{a0}(x)$$
then
$$\lim_{a\to\infty} f*g_{an}=f^{(n)}$$
and (**third question**) whether the $n$-th derivative operator includes or not the normalization constant $N_n$ for $g_{an}$.